# Поиск числа в строке по ключевому слову

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка:

```
"12 random text key 123 random text 987"
```

Нужно вытащить оттуда только те цифры которые идут после ключевого слова `key`.

Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
String fragment = text.split("key")[1];
String num = fragment.replaceAll("\\D+", "");
```

Но цифры в конце все равно остаются и вместо `123` я получаю `123987`. Мне нужно отрезыть все буквы после `123`. Или возможно есть более изящьный вариант. Может это можно одним регулярным выражением решить?

Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пожалуйста.

```
//Основной метод приложения
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String text = "12 random text key 123 random text 987";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=key\\s)(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    matcher.find();
    String result = matcher.group(1); //result = "123"
}
```

**UPD**

Дополнительный пример по просьбе автора с возможностью менять **key**:

```
//Основной метод приложения
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String key = "ABCDkeyA";
    String text = "12 random text ABCDkeyA 123 random text 987";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=" + key + "\\s)(\\d+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    matcher.find();
    String result = matcher.group(1); //result = "123"
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ваш ответ. А не подскажите еще один нюанс: если `key` у меня имеет вид переменной, как мне поместить его в регулятное выражение?

Comment: @Pavel, не совсем понимаю что вы имеете ввиду под переменной. Вы хотите искать конкретное значение? Ну то есть может быть kay 123 ?

Comment: key это условный пример ключа который приходит в виде аргумента в метод.

Comment: @Pavel, так регулярка же берется из строки, просто вместо `key` конкатенируйте свою переменную